# upload a csv to aws s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

```
def store_to_10_rss(tempDF):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    try:
        s3.Object('abcData', 'cr/working-files/unstructured_data/news-links/10_rss.csv').load()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print('\nThe object does not exist.')
            tempDF.to_csv('10_rss.csv')
            s3.Object('abcData/cr/working-files/unstructured_data/news-links/', '10_rss.csv').upload_file(Filename='10_rss.csv')
       
        else:
            print('\nSomething else has gone wrong.') 
            raise
    else:
        print('\nThe object does exist.')
```

In my S3, there are multiple buckets. I want to go to abcData bucket. Inside this bucket I want to go to cr folder, then to -->working-files folder, then to-->unstructured_data folder, then to-->news-links folder. In the news-links folder I want to check if a csv '10_rss' exists or not. If it doesn't exist, i want to store the passed dataframe ' tempDF' in a csv and upload this file to the path 'abcData/cr/working-files/unstructured_data/news-links/'.
But this gives me an error :
**ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "sgfr01data/credit-memorandum/working-files/unstructured_data/news-links/": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}$"**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the syntax of AWS S3 upload_file. Refer [these](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html) file upload examples from AWS. Also, you can refer [AWS boto3 API guide](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) for more details about same.

In-short, in your current error and sample code, you used combination of AWS S3 bucket keys or AWS S3 folders along with with AWS S3 bucket name, which should not be case for `upload_file` boto3 api. AWS S3 bucket name i.e. `sgfr01data` must be separate parameter.